# For a C program, I had to accept 5 element of an array from a user and copy them to another array using pointers, but I keep getting the wrong output

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Write a program to accept 5 integer elements of an array and copy them to another array, but all tasks must be performed using pointers.

```
// Here is my  program

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
  int arr[5], brr[5], *p, *q, i;
  p = arr;
  q = brr;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Enter any 5 element=");
    scanf("%d", (p + i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    brr[i] = arr[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Copied array elements are=%d", brr);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: What syntax error?

Comment: Sorry I meant wrong output

Comment: `printf("Copied array elements are=%d",*(brr + i));` or `*brr++`

Comment: What wrong output? Please show input, output and expected output. Also please apply some proper indentation to make your code readable.

Comment: You probably want to print value `brr[i]`

Comment: @JoopEggen Perhaps, you meant to place the parenthesis around `brr`: `(*brr)++`. Otherwise, `expression must be a modifiable lvalue` error is generated as of the c99 standard.

Comment: @Musing_soul if any of the answers given have been helpful, then please accept one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct except for the line where you're placing the output where you aren't using a pointer to the elements of `brr`.

Try

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     printf("Copied array elements are=%d\n",*(q+i));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```cpp
printf("Copied array elements are=%d", brr);
```

You are telling the system to display the `brr` (of type `int[]` — synonymous to `int*`) with `%d` that expects an integer. That leads to the problem.

You want to:

```c
printf("Copied array elements are = ");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    // Accessing the array element in a sequence.
    // NOTE: brr[i] could also be used, but pointer is used for this question.
    // brr[i] is the syntactic sugar of *(brr + i). No key differences.
    printf("%d ", *(brr + i));

printf("\n");
```

As a side note, you want to:

```c
printf("Enter any 5 element = ");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    scanf("%d", (p + i));
```